# Flow not running correctly for User.

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a Javascript Button that launches a flow. When I run this flow as a Admin everything works great. It takes input from a screen, updates a field on the Oppty, Creates a Chatter Post, and Creates a Activity.

However, when I test this as a user, it goes straight to the end of the flow saying Your Flow is Complete. It makes you updates to the Field or Posts.

Why is it skipping to the end of the flow?

Comment: might be useful to see some of the details of your flow. Does the flow logic actually work? (You stated "it makes you updates to the Field or Posts", but I'm guessing that's a typo.)